# Identify simple trend in a data sequence in R

Tags: r, trend

I have data organized by the year it was collected. I would like to know how do I know if there was a trend of increase, decrease or stabilization of the data during the period.

I can do this manually, plotting the plots with `ggplot` and then visually checking for trends. But this would be unfeasible because I have many columns with data. I would like to do something automatic.

for example visually checking, I see a slight upward trend for the `var1` variable:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(year=c(2000,2001,2001,2002,2000,2002,2000,2001,2002,2001),
           var1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           var2=c(2,3,6,4,8,12,13,4,21,3),
           var3=c(0.3,8,6,5,3,2,1,0.6,0.8,0.5),
           var4=sample(-5:5, size = 10))
df

ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=var1))+
  geom_point(aes(color = "Mean"), size=2.5)+
  stat_smooth(aes(color = "Trend"), se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Would there be a possibility for R to do this check automatically? and create a new column indicating the variables increased, decreased or stabilized in variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows for each variable the estimate of the slope and the p-value.  Smaller p-values are more significant.  Here only var4 has a slope significantly different from zero at the 5% level but you could adjust what cutoff to use which does not change the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

lm(as.matrix(df[-1]) ~ year, df) %>%
  tidy %>%
  filter(term == "year")
## # A tibble: 4 × 6
##   response term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
##   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
## 1 var1     year     1.00       1.26     0.792  0.451 
## 2 var2     year     2.33       2.49     0.937  0.376 
## 3 var3     year     0.583      1.16     0.504  0.628 
## 4 var4     year     2.50       1.07     2.34   0.0476


library(lattice)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-year) |>
  xyplot(value ~ year | name, data = _, type = c("p", "r"), as.table = TRUE)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does the `estimate` column indicate the slope of the trend line?

Comment: Yes, that is what the answer means when it says "This shows for each variable the estimate of the slope".

Comment: I tested it here and it solves my problem, but I still don't understand how the `estimate` column works? Does it create a linear regression and calculate the angle?

Comment: Yes,`lm` regresses each column on the LHS of the formula against `year` and then `tidy` converts that to a data frame and finally we keep just the rows for the `year` coefficients using `filter` as those coefficients are the slopes -- the omitted rows correspond to the intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Rob Hyndman's package (which is a part of the tidyverse making manipulations fast and simple) tsibble. It is a time series tibble object.

From there you can use a bunch of tools Rob created with the help and input of other forecasting experts (though he is magnificent on his own) and some of the most influential creators of the Tidyverse in .

He has authored a book, [Forecasting Principals & Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/components.html) explaining so much about time series, and it is open sourced.

Here is an example from chapter three on how to decompose data (a time series processing method) then extract a plot of the trend:

```
 require(tsibble)

 #decompose the data into time series components
 dcmp <- df%>%
 model(stl = STL(df))

 #plot the original points with trend
 components(dcmp) %>%
 as_tsibble() %>%
 autoplot(df, colour="gray") +
 geom_line(aes(y=trend), colour = "#ffffff") +
 labs(
   y = "Var1",
   title = "Something Witty Here"
 )
```

I would take the time to read chapters 1-3 it is not hard reading, it is aimed at application not mathematical understanding. So everything you read will be worthy!

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

After splitting the long format data by groups a model is fit and the extremes of `year` used to predict from the models. The differences between the first and last can be positive, negative or zero.

```r
library(ggplot2)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

df<-data.frame(year=c(2000,2001,2001,2002,2000,2002,2000,2001,2002,2001),
               var1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
               var2=c(2,3,6,4,8,12,13,4,21,3),
               var3=c(0.3,8,6,5,3,2,1,0.6,0.8,0.5),
               var4=sample(-5:5, size = 10))

old_opts <- options("warn")
options(warn = -1)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "stat") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, color = stat)) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "stat") %>%
  group_split(stat) %>%
  map_lgl(\(d) {
    fit <- loess(value ~ year, d)
    year <- range(d$year)
    pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(year))
    diff(pred) > 0
  })
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

options(old_opts)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>